# Unable to determine type for field 'T_DATE'. warnings.warn("Unable to determine type for field '{}'.".format(bq_field.name))

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I want to convert the biquery query result into dataframe using following code. Same code works file on **google jupyterLab Notebook** but throwing error on my local.

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, location=bq_location)
    query_job = bq_client.query(sql, project=project_id)
    result = query_job.result()
    schema = result.schema
    df = result.to_dataframe()
```

**schema** look like

```
[SchemaField('T_DATE', 'DATE', 'NULLABLE')]
```

```
C:Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py:244: UserWarning: Unable to determine type for field 'T_DATE'.
  warnings.warn("Unable to determine type for field '{}'.".format(bq_field.name))
Traceback (most recent call last):
df = result.to_dataframe()
  File "Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\table.py", line 1941, in to_dataframe
    create_bqstorage_client=create_bqstorage_client,
  File "Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\table.py", line 1733, in to_arrow
    bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client
  File "Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\table.py", line 1630, in _to_page_iterable
    yield from result_pages
  File "Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py", line 628, in download_arrow_row_iterator
    yield _row_iterator_page_to_arrow(page, column_names, arrow_types)
  File "Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py", line 601, in _row_iterator_page_to_arrow
    arrays.append(pyarrow.array(page._columns[column_index], type=arrow_type))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

using pandas = 1.3.4 and bigquery - 2.28.1

Comment: It looks like `result` is nullable or dont have any values, can you check if you can print `result` or check for any errors on BQ job history

Comment: @Prany Row((datetime.date(2015, 5, 12)...) I can see the data in result and non of the row is null, it is also defined as nullable in schema.

Comment: Did not solution for the issue, currently implementing a work around by converting the **RowIterator** into list and then using pd.Dataframe() to convert into dataframe.

    result = query_job.result()
    schema = result.schema
    df = result.to_dataframe()
    header = []
    for row in schema:
        header.append(row.name)
    ls = []
    for row in result:
        temp_list = []
        for data in row:
            temp_list.append(data)
        ls.append(temp_list)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=header)

Comment: Can you paste some sample data, I can try to recreate this

Answer (score 1):

```
df = bq_client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()
```

Looks like `result()` is causing the problem. This worked for me.